# Prove the following statement...

Tags: limits

So, how can I prove this limit: $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2}=+\infty$$
What I've tried is to multiply both numerator and denominator with (x+x0), but I guess that's wrong, what can I do to solve this? Please help...

Comment: It is the same as : $\lim\limits_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x>0}} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$

Comment: You can try to prove that $ \lim_{x\to x_o} \frac{1}{x-x_o} = +\infty $

Comment: @user2768645 this is false, since the limit depends on the constraints of a sequence.
$$\lim_{x\nearrow 0} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty \neq \infty = \lim_{x\searrow 0} \frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens to the denominator as $x \to x_0$?

Since $(x - x_0)$ is squared, it is positive regardless of whether we approach $x_0$ from the left or right. Hence, the denominator *shrinks* towards zero (becoming incredibly small, yet remaining positive) as $x\to x_0,\;$ and thus the resultant function approaches $+\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, once it'll be 1/0.0000000000000000000000...1, and it's +inf. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: You're welcome, A6Tech.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x-x_o=t$, we only need to  prove
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t^2}=+\infty$$
$$\forall G >0, \exists \delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}, |t|<\delta, 
\frac{1}{t^2}>G $$
Then by definition, we proof this equation.